# Django регистрация | Как убрать выбор профиля для нового пользователя?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. После регистрации пользователя и дальнейшей его авторизации у него ограниченный доступ к загрузке изображения, вообще не может ничего загрузить. Но после добавления профиля через админку у пользователя появляются права на загрузку любых изображений.
Как убрать "выбор профиля" для новых зарегистрированных пользователей? Чтобы самому вручную этим не заниматься.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone



class Profile(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  bio = models.CharField(default='Привет, всем!', max_length=100)
  image = models.ImageField(default='def_user.png')

  def str(self):
    return f'Профиль {self.user.username}'

  def following(self):
    user_ids = Relationship.objects.filter(from_user=self.user)\
                    .values_list('to_user_id', flat=True)
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)


  def followers(self):
    user_ids = Relationship.objects.filter(to_user=self.user)\
                    .values_list('from_user_id', flat=True)
    return User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids)



class Post(models.Model):
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  content = models.TextField()
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts')


  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

  def str(self):
    return self.content


class Relationship(models.Model):
  from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='relationships', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='related_to', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def str(self):
    return f'{self.from_user} to {self.to_user}'
```

Comment: Если я верно вас понял то проблема в том что в модели пользователя отсутствует атрибут картинка - соответственно  он не может её загрузить. Чтобы сделать то что вам нужно можно либо переопределить модель пользователя, либо при регистрации создавать объект Profile для пользователя (можно реализовать во вьюшке).

Comment: Сигналы надо прописать, до них не додумался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```